# How to return the result based on Queryset in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am writing a Django Rest API and my use case is like this:

Here is my endpoint: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/totalclinic/slug=abc&date=9-10-21

This will return all the query result of the doctor ABC who worked on this particular date.

```
{
        "doctor_name": "ABC",
        "slug": "abc",
        "working_date": "2019-10-21T07:32:24Z",
        "clinic": "xyx",
}
```

I am using Generic ListAPIView for this and my requirement is to count the number of clinics visited by a doctor using the result of a query set and print it.

Is there any way to print my own count result instead of queryset result when user types http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/totalclinic/slug=abc&date=9-10-21.

Answer (score 0):

The response for `ListView` is controlled by the pagination class, so you need to customise that class. The solution for this case is well documented:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles